# How to do data join in Hadoop v2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am not able to find classes like `DataJoinMapperBase`, `DataJoinReducerBasea` and `TaggedMapOutput` in **v2.2.0**. Which jar file should have these classes and where can I find it ?

Thanks